# error in website into host

Tags: networking, server, sqlexception

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)]

Comment: hi...i have a website and put into host plesk and when run the website i have error please help me

Comment: Try providing some details. What is the connection string. Have you tested the connection details in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve “A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time” error in asp.net